# signalR change default site in startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an application where i have 2 instances of it running on the same IIS server.

- /Site1
- /Site2

same source code in both, just different settings.  I have signalR code on both sites, but i would like Site2 to use the signalR server from Site1.

I have this working so that if changes are made on Site1, Site2 knows to refresh, and that works fine.  THE PROBLEM is that if server changes (not javascript) are made on Site2, Site1 doesn't get them.  Below is my code:

**Startup.cs**

```
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
#if DEBUG
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
#endif
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

**javascript code:**

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://servername/Site1/signalr";
...$.connection.start etc
```

All of that seems to work fine, but what i can't find anywhere is how to push settings in the C# code from Site2 to Site1.

**random c# code:**

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<myHub>();
```

this globalhost.connectionmanager.gethubcontext is always pointing to itself.  How can i get Site2 to point to Site1 in the last section?  I've tried looking into editing Startup.cs to use MapSignalR(..path,...), but the path doesn't take absolute URLs, it has to start with '/', so it won't go up a level.

Any ideas or am i missing something basic?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what i'm looking for is a backplane.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr .  super easy to set up, and fixed my problem immediately (without any of the javascript changes above needed).